# How to download ArgoUML source code from the Tigris website using Subversion client?

Tags: svn, argouml

Sorry for maybe this is stupid question, I just want download source code form the link as follows: http://argouml.tigris.org/source/browse/argouml/trunk/src/

I try to use the command:

```
svn checkout http://argouml.tigris.org/source/browse/argouml/trunk/
```

but it throw error :

> svn: OPTIONS of 'http://argouml.tigris.org/source/browse/argouml/trunk': 200 OK (http://argouml.tigris.org)

I am strange that , how to checkout the source code from the url ?

Many thanks for your help!

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detailed instructions here 
http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/source/browse/argouml-downloads/

Answer (score 6):

Tigris.org is using authentication on their SVN connection, so you need to say that you are the user "guest" (no password), like this:

```
svn checkout http://argouml.tigris.org/svn/argouml/trunk argouml --username guest
```